# Dr. Strange's preoccupation with time before being entrusted with the Time Stone

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, doctor-strange

At the very beginning of the movie, we see Dr. Stephen Strange ask a colleague to cover his watch while in the operating room.

[image]

We then see Strange looking through his vast collection of watches just before his accident.

[image]

I never caught anything in the dialogue about having an affinity for watches or having a fear of watches in the operating room, but it seems almost foreshadowing that his destiny would be tied to time.

Was this ever mentioned in either the movie or the source comics as to whether or not Stephen Strange had a "thing" about time before becoming Dr. Strange, the superhero?

Comment: He wants the watch covered because the ticking is distracting him from the surgery. He has lots of watches because that's the sort of thing wealthy professionals have lots of.

Comment: As Paul Lehman pointed out in his now-deleted answer, Strange was in the previous operating room answering trivia questions.  Saying the watch "distracted him" seems a bit uncharacteristic, as it appears he uses the distractions as a tool to keep himself calm.

Answer (score 10):

The first scene was a very general one where most surgeons avoid distactions even as slightest as the sound of that watch ticking, As for the second scene was more important in showing how lavish life he used to live as right during that scene we see his closet,house and expensive car to support this notion.
He never had a thing for time and was never refrenced as even in the end it was more of his ability to control it apart from the ancient one

Comment: Maybe they planned it when writing the movie, but as you said in the movie there's no apparent connection.